# How can I change a part of a filename with python

Tags: python, filenames, filepath

I am brand new to python (and coding in general) and I've been unable to find a solution to my specific problem online. I am currently creating a tool which will allow a user to save a file to a network location. The file will have a version number. What I would like to is to have the script auto version up before it saves. I have the rest of the script done, but it is the auto versioning that I am having issues with. Here's what I have so far:

```
import re
import os

def main():
    wip_folder = "L:/xxx/xxx/xxx/scenes/wip/"  
    _file_list = os.listdir('%s' % wip_folder)

    if os.path.exists('%s' wip_path):
        for file in _file_list:
            versionPattern = re.compile('_v\d{3}')
            curVersions = versionPattern.findall('%s' % wip_folder)
            curVersions.sort()
            nextVersion = '_v%03d' % (int(curVersions[-1][2:]) + 1)
        return nextVersion
    else:
        nextVersion = '_v001'

    name = xxx_xxx_xx
    name += '%s' nextVersion
    name += '_xxx_wip
```

I should probably point out that main() is going to be called by a QPushbutton in another module. Also, that wip_path will most likely have several versions of a single file in it. So if there are 10 versions of this file in wip_path, this save should be v011. I apologize if this question makes no sense. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Not entirely sure what problem your are having. Are you only trying to determine how to find past versions and correctly name the new one?

Comment: basically, yes. I need to go through the wip folder to find the highest version number. I then need to add 1 to that version version number to get a string which I am storing in the variable nextVersion. I'm then tacking that on to the final naming convention. Basically, if my wip directory has
ex_v001.doc
ex_v002.doc
ex_v003.doc
in it, I want my next save to be named:
ex_v004.doc

Comment: You only need to compile your regex once, outside the loop. Your question *does* makes sense btw. but it's not clear what your problem is. What's your current output? How isn't it working at the moment?

Comment: I've been testing it by trying print name to make sure that I'm actually getting the proper naming convention, but pycharm doesn't print anything

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use re at all, programming is about simplification and you are over complicating it! I chose to return but anything in this function can be changed to whatever you need it to specifically do! Just read the comments and good luck!

```
def getVersioning(path):
    #passing path

    count = 1 #init count
    versionStr = 'wip_path_v'
    try: #in case path dosen't exist
        for i in os.listdir(path): #loop thorough files in passed dir
            if versionStr in i: #check if files contain default versioning string e.g. wip_path_V or any other (used in case other files are in the same dir)
                count += 1 #incriment count
    except:
        os.mkdir(path) #makedir if one does not exist for future use

    newName = versionStr + str(count) #new versioning file name
    return newName #return new versioning name

print getVersioning('tstFold')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'll try this solution as soon as I can. I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: Glad I could help!